# How do I execute SQL queries against a RDS SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds

I am a newbie to AWS, and frankly to DB administration. I just installed a SQL Server instance, and now I would like to create tables, execute queries, etc.

Are there any free tools I can use to administrate the DB, and execute ddl and dml against this instance, from my Windows EC2 instance?

Also, how do I get that from my EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx).

Here's the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html) on how to connect.

Comment: Do you know how I can get Management Studio installed?

Comment: @VinnyGray Here's the download https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: @SQLChao Can u please help in my question on urgent basis?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747233/not-able-to-update-or-delete-some-of-records-in-rds-db